# Un Script que me valida letras funciona en el ordenador pero no en el movil

Tags: javascript

Tengo un codigo que solo me valide letras en un input en el computador funciona el script pero cuando me paso al celular ya deja de funcionar y ya admite los numeros.¿Como puedo hacer para que el script lo valide en el computador y celular?

```js
<script>
    function soloLetras(e){
       key = e.keyCode || e.which;
       tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();
       letras = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz:.";
       especiales = "8-37-39-46";

       tecla_especial = false
       for(var i in especiales){
            if(key == especiales[i]){
                tecla_especial = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(letras.indexOf(tecla)==-1 && !tecla_especial){
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<input onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)" type="text"  name="asd">
```

---

En Google Chrome, el codigo no funciona en esta plataforma; pero cuando lo ejecuto funciona bien pero solo en el computador :D y no en el celular :(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y EN EL CELULAR!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Revisa los eventos que tienes para un input en móvil, probablemente es que keypress no está disponible en los móviles. Y podrían cambiar los eventos de un navegador a otro también.

Comment: qué se supone que son las letras especiales? no debieran ser un array?

Comment: @amenadiel , con un String también vale, ya que String permite búsquedas para saber si contiene un carácter, entonces, lo que está haciendo es meter todas las letras en un String, y si al pulsar una tecla no lo encuentra en el String, entonces no es una letra.

Comment: @chikebox claro un string es iterable, pero creo que la idea del OP es ver si la tecla pulsada es `%`, `'` o `.`. La primera no sé qué es

Answer (score 0):

Puedes proceder del siguiente modo:

- Obtén el valor del input que recibe lo que el usuario teclea
- Usa la función **`match`** que se encarga de encontrar las coincidencias dada una expresión regular
- Como el método `match` retorna **`true`** o **`false`** dependiendo si la regex se cumple; entonces basta con colocar esto: **`input.value.match(/[A-Za-z]/)`**
- La expresión regular se compone de 2 rangos, el primero de las letras en mayúscula y el segundo de las letras en minúscula
- Usamos el símbolo **`^`** para validar la existencia de una coincidencia al inicio de una cadena y **`$`** para encontrar si existe la coincidencia al final de la cadena

Código

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="#">
      <input type="text" id="name" />
      <button id="boton">Valida texto</button>
      <div id="aviso"></div>
    <script>    
        let boton = document.getElementById("boton")
        
        boton.addEventListener("click", function validar(event) {
          event.preventDefault()
          let name  = document.getElementById("name")
          let aviso = document.getElementById("aviso")
          
          if(name.value.match(/^[A-Za-z]$/)) {
            aviso.innerHTML = "es válido por que es texto"
          }else{
            aviso.innerHTML = "No es válido"
            name.value = ""
            name.focus()
          }
        })
    </script>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Pero si añado texto y luego numero, sigue siendo valido

Comment: @CamiloLince revisa si la edición te ayuda